# How to enforce a nullable foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, foreign-key

I have a relation between two tables.  The foreign key table can have a row related in the primary table.  There's a way to enforce the value of the FK column to be NULL or one of the values of the PK column in the primary table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can allow a foreign key column to be NULL, making it an *optional* relation.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(fooid INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE dbo.bar(barid INT PRIMARY KEY,
  fooid INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.foo(fooid));

INSERT dbo.foo SELECT 1;
INSERT dbo.bar SELECT 1,1;
INSERT dbo.bar SELECT 2,NULL; -- succeeds
GO
INSERT dbo.bar SELECT 3,2; -- fails
```

If this is not what you meant, then please elaborate or re-word your question.

Comment: You're right.  I was confused with not enforced FK.  Now I understand that not enforcing the FK only can help for data migration, but otherwise a FK allways must be enforced.